# How to Change Wordpress Image URLs

Tags: images

I am facing a problem related to image URLs on one of the website that is bestappspoint.com
Most of the images in this site are with capital letters in URL (I didn't know the consequences before) but now I want to redirect all the capital letter in URLs through `.htaccess` file or by adding a rule in SQL databases through phpMyAdmin. Please guide me the rule how to do it.
For example: One URL with capital letters is:

```
http://www.bestappspoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Talking-Speedometer.jpg
```

I want such all URLs to be redirected like:

```
http://www.bestappspoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/talking-speedometer.jpg
```

In the lower image, URL has no capital letters. Can you guide me what `.htaccess` rule or phpMyAdmin should be added to solve this major problem so that there are no more 404 pages on my website.

Comment: Did you try [CheckCaseOnly](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_speling.html#checkcaseonly) ?

Answer (score 1):

you can either use a Plugin for redirection: http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/
(would be like editing the `.htaccess`)

OR use a Plugin to edit the wordpress database (make sure to do a database backup first)
http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/